# How to store only hh:mm in the datetime field?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date, ef-code-first, data-annotations

I'm using codefirst with dataannotation attributes. The model looks like that:

```
    public class Incident
{
    [Key]
    public int IncidentId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm}")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Create view:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, "time")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
```

And when I'm trying to create new model, I get validation message near this field. I've even tried to pass current date to the view from create method, but it doesn't help.
Is there a way to store only hh:mm (without dd/MM/yyyy)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are really only interested in time of day, then perhaps use a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `DateTime`

Answer (score 2):

Use TimeSpan.

Have a nice day,

Alberto

Comment: +1 as you must have been typing this as I submitted my answer :)

Comment: Hahaha I just noticed you did answer... and before me! Well done :)